# how to search from array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am making an E-commerce website in `PHP` and I have a product table where I am storing 3 different prices :

1. wholesale price
2. sale price
3. regular price

Now Instead of making 3 columns for 3 prices I stored those prices in an array and store that array in SQL database.

Now the problem is supposed I want to select products based on the wholesale price only. Let say,

`"select * from table where wholesale price = 100"`.

How can I do this ?

I haven't tried any code yet because I am confused and have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Why did you decide to store them as an array? Was there a specific need?

Comment: Man there are so many things related to a single products. So I think making different column in database for every specification of product will be lengthy and problematic. That's why I used array@Sami Kuhmonen

Comment: Have a look at how to design a database properly.  What if you wanted a trade price or other types.  Ideally you would have a price type, so you could then say "select * from table where price_type = 2 and price = 100" for example.  (have a look third normal form)

Comment: what are you trying to say? Be clear@Nigel Ren. And what is third normal form

Comment: Please have a look at [DB normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have the concept of arrays - you can have a comma separated string but since it's just a string you cannot refer to the individual elements in any way. MYSQL does have some string handling ability so you could split a 3 element string quite easily for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(prod int,p varchar(100));
insert into t values
(1,'10,20,30'),
(2,'40,50'),
(3,'60'),
(4,'70,80,90,100');



select prod,
         substring_index(p,',',1)  WholesalePrice,
         substring_index(substring_index(p,',',2),',',-1)  SalePrice,
         substring_index(p,',',-1) RegularPrice
from t;

+------+----------------+-----------+--------------+
| prod | WholesalePrice | SalePrice | RegularPrice |
+------+----------------+-----------+--------------+
|    1 | 10             | 20        | 30           |
|    2 | 40             | 50        | 50           |
|    3 | 60             | 60        | 60           |
|    4 | 70             | 80        | 100          |
+------+----------------+-----------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

note the useful(sic) effect of having anything other than 3 string elements. Anyone looking at the data wouldn't know what the string element pertain to. 
'every specification of product will be lengthy and problematic' - most here would suggest storing csv values is more problematic in the long run than normalising the data.